# Secure Shuffle techniques?

Tags: cryptography, shuffle

Can anyone help me point out known shuffle techniques that are considered secure?

Any paper/technique name reference would help ( I tried to search it up with not decisive results showing)

Appreciate any kind of help

Comment: "secure" is an empty term. What is considered secure depends on the context: Which situations would you like to prevent, and which situations do you not care about?

Comment: My probability teacher use to ask the question :If you had a perfectly random deck of cards if you shuffled one more time do you get a deck that is more or less random"?  Something that is secure is random so you can't get decipher the message easily without knowing the key.  Shuffling adds another level of encrypting and is not really very secure because it can easily be broken.

Comment: I think this question should be reworded a bit; asking about "secure shuffling algorithms used for lists" would make this on topic. Note that any shuffling algorithm that doesn't take a cryptographically secure entropy source as input is probably bunk. Many API's already have shuffling implemented, e.g. [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-java.util.Random-) although you should parameterize it with a seeded `SecureRandom` instance, not just `Random`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, a perefectly-random implementation of something like the Fisher-Yates algorithm would yield a completely random shuffle. In practice, howerver, Fisher-Yates is susceptible to things like modulo bias. See some of the pitfalls in [relevant section in the Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Potential_sources_of_bias) and [How Not To Shuffle The Knuth-Fisher-Yates Algorithm](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/theory/2744-how-not-to-shuffle-the-kunth-fisher-yates-algorithm.html).

Knuth's classic [The Art Of Computer Programming (Volume 2)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201896842) - discusses a possibly suitable algorithm by MacLaren and Marsaglia.

Finally, see also [Cryptographic Shuffling of Random and
Pseudorandom Sequences](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/volltexte/2007/1014/pdf/07021.DichtlMarkus.Paper.1014.pdf).